# GNOME session not starting after filesystem corruption

Tags: gnome, xorg, 9.10

I'm running Ubuntu 9.10 desktop edition. Suddenly today /home became corrupted and I was prompted to run `fsck` manually. I ran `fsck -y /home` and rebooted the system. The system booted but I got no GUI interface (GNOME session) but a black screen with a user prompt instead. Any tricks here to start my system normally? Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:1**

The error were similar to the the following(may be with some mistakes as I had to type it manually):

machine1 login: root

password:

at login Sun Jan 16 15:30:46 IST 2011 on tty1

EXT3-fs error (devie sda1): ext3_lookup :deleted inode referenced

aborting journal on device sda1

Remounting filesystem read-only

```
root@machine1:~# startx
ktemp: failed to create file via template `/tmp/serverauth.xxxxxxxxxxx: Read-only file
/usr/bin/startx: line 157: cannot create temp file for here-document: Read-only file
xauth: error in locking authority file /root/.Xauthority
/usr/bin/startx: line 173: cannnot create temp file for here-document: Read-only file
xauth: error in locking authority file /root/.Xauthority
/usr/bin/startx: line 173: cannnot create temp file for here-document: Read-only file
X: cannot stat /tmp/.x11-unix (No such file or directory), aborting giving up.
xinit: No such file or directory (errno 2): unable to connect to xserver
xinit: No such process (errno 3): Server error
xauth: error in locking authority file /root/.Xauthority
```

Comment: In the prompt,type the following and see if it helps you  `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg`

Comment: What happens when you press `Ctrl+Alt+F7`?

Comment: I'll try this two options!

Comment: I was not at that system. Running fsck on / fixed the issue and booted gnome. I simply did `fsck -y /` and I think there would be some better way to do this without corrupting the file system(some times fsck may corrupt on a way to recover). Any one could tell me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just running `fsck -y /`, or `fsck -y /dev/sda1` fixed the issue and system started gnome as usual. The best way of running fsck would be booting the system from live cd or usb stick. But before running fsck, backing up necessary data is also to be considered mandatory.

Comment: wow, now my linux mint is constantly rebooting (after `fsck -y /`). Any ideas how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Log in and try `startx`

Is your /home on a separate partition?

Comment: yes it's on separate partition

Comment: I've updated my question!

Comment: You can't run startx as root. Log in as your normal user.